# Display a file dialog that prompts only for Eclipse Project File location

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-plugin

How can I arbitrarily display the same file dialog that occurs from `New -> File`?

I have an Eclipse `Action` where I wish to display the project file path dialog, and not the system file path dialog, as seen in this image:

[image: Eclipse Project File Dialog]

Also there is one catch: I want to display existing files too, as I will not be creating a new file, but instead may be overwriting/synchronizing a file. If this is NOT possible, I'll still want to know how to just display the same dialog as is in `New -> File`.

Answer (score 2):

To display a workspace file picker, you will need to do something along these lines:

```
ElementTreeSelectionDialog dialog = new ElementTreeSelectionDialog(
    shell,
    new WorkbenchLabelProvider(),
    new WorkbenchContentProvider());

dialog.setInput(ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot());
dialog.setAllowMultiple(false);

if (dialog.open() == Window.OK) {
    IResource resource = (IResource) dialog.getFirstResult();
}
```

`ElementTreeSelectionDialog` is quite customizable, so you can tune the behavior to your needs.

Comment: This dialog doesn't allow the  user to select a currently non-existent file, however.